# Python - Deleting sub-folder (Delete only sub-folder and not the other files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, delete-file

I have a folder that contains a sub-folder and set of text files. I am trying to delete the sub-folder using the below code

```
Path = '/Desktop/foldername/'
folder = 'Path/'
for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I keep getting an error folder does not exist. Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess, do you have `Desktop` in your root file system? Because if you're looking for `~/Desktop` that's some where else.

Comment: @Torxed, the path is right.

Comment: But you get an error saying it isn't? That's suspicious. Can you do a `ls -l /` for me?

Comment: If you don't want other files to be deleted then you simply shouldn't do `os.unlink(file_path)`.

Comment: Your `Path` variable isn't used at all. Did you mean to use it to initialize the `folder` variable?

Comment: @blhsing, yes am I doing it wrong